# getting error --->has been blocked by CORS policy:

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, cors

```
// code of react js for post request ---->>>
-----------------------------------------------
export const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080";


export const myAxios = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
});

export const privateAxios = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    
  },
 
});

privateAxios.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    const token = getToken();

    if (token) {
      // config.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
      config.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
      // console.log(config);
    }

    return config;
  },
  (error) => Promise.reject(error)
);

export const createPost = (user) => {
  return  privateAxios
    .post("/profile/v2/add/post", user)
    .then((val) => {
      console.log(val);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));

};
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// cors config in spring boot ---->>>>

@Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean crossFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));

        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedOriginPattern("*");
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("Authorization");
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("Content-Type");
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("Accept");
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        corsConfiguration.setMaxAge(3600L);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);

        return bean;

    }
```

i am trying to post but i am getting   Error--->>

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/profile/v2/add/post' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For CORS configuration on spring boot you can use configuration which implements `WebMvcConfigurer`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```